# jquery/js: OnFocus OnBlur?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, i wish to make an ajax call if it has lost the focus from my site for 1 minute, so when it's onfocus again it send an ajax call? 
How can i do that?

Comment: What is the 'it' to which you refer? And, from your question, you seem to imply you want an ajax call to fire both onFocus and onBlur events, do you want one, or both?

Comment: it = my site, e.g if while youre on the page and you enter a new tab/window/do something else on your pc, then when you get back(on focus) it should check for if the page has been over 1 minute since it lost onblur( the focus), and if it did that then run a ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Give it a try:

```
$(function() {
    var tracktime;

    $(window).blur(function() {
        tracktime = new Date();
    })
    .focus(function() {
        if(tracktime && new Date() - tracktime > 60000) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/your/path/',
                success:function() {
                    alert('ajax returned')
                }
            })
        }
        tracktime = null;
    });
});
```